# Repeating values on recursive sudoku solver in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sudoku

I'm trying to make a sudoku solver using recursion by storing possible values in a dictionary with index as key and the set of possible values as value. Parameter b is just the board expressed as a single list, and .get_row, .get_col, .get_box methods return their respective values properly. If an entry in the dictionary has a set with a single element then it gets put into the board b, otherwise if there's no possible set with a single element a value gets picked from the set of possible numbers and the recursion starts. This is the full repeatable code:

```
class Sudoku:
    def solve_it(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> None:
        """
        :param board: sudoku board gets modified inplace at .create_board_from_list
        :return: None
        """
        unit_values = []
        for i in range(len(board)):  # flattening the board into unit_values
            for j in range(len(board[i])):
                unit_values.append(board[i][j])
        self.go_through_recursive(board, unit_values)

    def get_row(self, n: int, b):  # retrieve all elements of nth row in the board
        assert 0 <= n <= 8
        return set(b[9 * n: 9 * (n + 1)])

    def get_col(self, n: int, b):  # retrieve all elements of nth col in the board
        assert 0 <= n <= 8
        return set(b[n::9])

    def get_box(self, n: int, b):  # retrieve all elements of nth box in the board
        assert 0 <= n <= 8
        return set(b[i] for i in range(81) if (i // 27) == (n // 3) and i % 9 // 3 == n % 3)

    def go_through_recursive(self, board, b, d=False):
        """
        :param board: sudoku board as matrix where each row is a line
        :param b: sudoku board as a single long list
        """
        numbers = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
        while True:

            if d:
                return True

            missing_dict = {}  # populate missing_dict
            for idx in range(len(b)):
                if b[idx] == '.':
                    row, col, box = idx // 9, idx % 9, (idx // 27) * 3 + (idx % 9) // 3
                    # union of all the present values in current row, col and box
                    values = self.get_row(row, b).union(self.get_col(col, b)).union(self.get_box(box, b))
                    values.remove('.')
                    missing_ones = numbers.difference(values)  # possible values to input in the slot
                    if len(missing_ones) == 0:  # impossible to continue
                        return False
                    missing_dict[idx] = missing_ones

            old_count = b.count('.')
            # now we iterate through the dictionary of possible values per index,
            # if one index has a set with a single number it means that that's the only possible number so we store it
            for idx, missings in missing_dict.items():  # store assured values
                if len(missings) == 1:
                    b[idx] = missings.pop()

            if b.count('.') == 0:  # check if complete
                self.create_board_from_list(board, b)
                return True

            if b.count('.') == old_count:  # if no progress has been made
                for idx, s in missing_dict.items():  # iterate through the dictionary
                    for number in s:  # create a new board and store indecisive value then recur
                        if d:
                            return True
                        bb = b[:]
                        bb[idx] = number
                        d = self.go_through_recursive(board, bb)

    def create_board_from_list(self, board, b):
        temp_board = []
        chunk = 9
        for idx in range(0, len(b), chunk):
            temp_board.append(b[idx: idx + chunk])
        for idx in range(len(board)):
            board[idx] = temp_board[idx]
        print('done')
```

The issue I     have is that     once     it     completes, some     numbers     are     repeated(either in the     rows, cols or boxes).Also     I     've noticed that if I check the possible values inside the '     store     assured     values     ' loop it sometimes returns the whole range [1, 9] possibly being the reason of some rewriting:

```
row, col, box = idx // 9, idx % 9, (idx // 27) * 3 + (idx % 9) // 3
values = self.get_row(row, b).union(self.get_col(col, b)).union(self.get_box(box, b))
values.remove('.')  # some of these values are [1, 9]
```

Given this board input:

```
board = 
[[".",".","9","7","4","8",".",".","."],
 ["7",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
 [".","2",".","1",".","9",".",".","."],
 [".",".","7",".",".",".","2","4","."],
 [".","6","4",".","1",".","5","9","."],
 [".","9","8",".",".",".","3",".","."],
 [".",".",".","8",".","3",".","2","."],
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","6"],
 [".",".",".","2","7","5","9",".","."]]
```

the correct output is

```
board =
[["5","1","9","7","4","8","6","3","2"],
 ["7","8","3","6","5","2","4","1","9"],
 ["4","2","6","1","3","9","8","7","5"],
 ["3","5","7","9","8","6","2","4","1"],
 ["2","6","4","3","1","7","5","9","8"],
 ["1","9","8","5","2","4","3","6","7"],
 ["9","7","5","8","6","3","1","2","4"],
 ["8","3","2","4","9","1","7","5","6"],
 ["6","4","1","2","7","5","9","8","3"]]
```

while the code has the incorrect board

```
board = 
[["3","1","9","7","4","8","6","5","2"],
 ["7","8","5","6","3","2","1","1","9"],
 ["4","2","6","1","5","9","8","7","3"],
 ["5","3","7","9","8","6","2","4","1"],
 ["2","6","4","3","1","7","5","9","8"],
 ["1","9","8","5","2","4","3","6","7"],
 ["9","7","1","8","6","3","4","2","5"],
 ["8","5","2","4","9","1","7","3","6"],
 ["6","4","3","2","7","5","9","8","4"]]
```

EDIT:

I changed the `go_through_recursive` to store the unique possible value directly into the board, in this case the only possible set length in the dictionary is 2 or greater. But this seems to get stuck in an infinite loop

```
    def go_through_recursive(self, board, b, d=False):
        """
        :param board: sudoku board as matrix where each row is a line
        :param b: sudoku board as a single long list
        """
        numbers = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
        while True:

            old_count = b.count('.')
            missing_dict = {}  # populate missing_dict
            for idx in range(len(b)):
                if b[idx] == '.':
                    row, col, box = idx // 9, idx % 9, (idx // 27) * 3 + (idx % 9) // 3
                    # union of all the present values in current row, col and box
                    values = self.get_row(row, b).union(self.get_col(col, b)).union(self.get_box(box, b))
                    values.remove('.')
                    missing_ones = numbers.difference(values)  # possible values to input in the slot
                    if len(missing_ones) == 0:  # impossible to continue
                        return False
                    elif len(missing_ones) == 1:
                        b[idx] = missing_ones.pop()
                    else:
                        missing_dict[idx] = missing_ones

            if b.count('.') == 0:  # check if complete
                self.create_board_from_list(board, b)
                return True

            if b.count('.') == old_count:  # if no progress has been made
                for idx, s in missing_dict.items():  # iterate through the dictionary
                    for number in s:  # create a new board and store indecisive value then recur
                        bb = b[:]
                        bb[idx] = number
                        if self.go_through_recursive(board, bb):
                            return True
```

Comment: Once you do `b[idx] = missings.pop()`, other values in missing_dict are invalidated and you need to update them.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I can now see that being the reason they return empty in store assured values loop. Still I don't get why I should update them, they will simply be empty sets once they are popped.

Comment: If you have two missing sets of `{1}` in the same row, you happily assign `1` to both cells and continue, producing an invalid row. Whereas you should assign `1` to the first cell, update the missing set in the second cell, see that it is now empty, and backtrack.

Comment: I changed `go_through_recursive` to directly store into the board the unique value, this seems to return the correct board but now it gets stuck into an infinite loop from time to time

Comment: Show an input board that gets you stuck.

Comment: The input board I posted is a good example. Sometimes it properly finishes and sometimes it gets stuck in a loop. I did some print debugging and it repeats the same couple of `missing_dict` meaning it gets stuck in the same states of the board looping through them. The reason that it doesn't happen all the time has probably to do with the fact that I'm using sets which are unordered objects, so the `for number in s` loop at the end is not the same at every run of the code.

Comment: Also, you now have posted two versions of your code, each apparently with different problems and thus different question. Can you focus on one question please? Which version of the code are you asking about?

Comment: i think that you should be doing back tracking which is a form of recursive. i could provide a solution this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in the first version of your code:

- When you do `b[idx] = missings.pop()` you should exit the loop, because now `missings` is no longer up-to-date: by placing a number on the grid, this number is no longer allowed on some other empty cells, and this is not correctly reflected in the dictionary. This bug is the cause of getting the same number twice on the same line. The easy fix is to exit the loop right after this assignment, so that the dictionary can be rebuilt in the next iteration of the outer loop
- Where you have the loop `for number in s`, you should consider that if none of these numbers leads to a solution (`d` is never `True`), you should not continue to try another entry from `missing_dict`, because if this one has no solution, it doesn't matter what you try elsewhere on the board: there is no solution. Instead you should backtrack with `return False` if this inner loop comes to an end without solution. This issue is the cause of an apparent "infinite" loop: there is an exponential number of combinations that gets tried in vain.

Not a problem, but as it is related to the second point's variable `d`: you have two places where you have `if d:`. You can easily avoid this duplication by placing this block right after you get the boolean back from recursion. Then you'll not even need the `d` parameter/variable.

Several other comments could be made, but correcting the above is enough to make it work. Here is the first version of your code with these corrections (The code comments indicate where a change was made):

```
    def go_through_recursive(self, board, b):  # No d argument needed
        numbers = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
        while True:
            # Removed the `if d` block from here. See further down.

            missing_dict = {}
            for idx in range(len(b)):
                if b[idx] == '.':
                    row, col, box = idx // 9, idx % 9, (idx // 27) * 3 + (idx % 9) // 3
                    values = self.get_row(row, b).union(self.get_col(col, b)).union(self.get_box(box, b))
                    values.remove('.')
                    missing_ones = numbers.difference(values)
                    if len(missing_ones) == 0:
                        return False
                    missing_dict[idx] = missing_ones

            old_count = b.count('.')
 
            for idx, missings in missing_dict.items():
                if len(missings) == 1:
                    b[idx] = missings.pop()
                    # Must break here because now missing_dict 
                    #    is no longer up to date!
                    break  

            if b.count('.') == 0:
                self.create_board_from_list(board, b)
                return True

            if b.count('.') == old_count:
                # Only get one entry from this dictionary (no loop)
                idx, s = next(iter(missing_dict.items()))  
                for number in s: 
                    bb = b[:]
                    bb[idx] = number
                    # Not needed to assign to d, 
                    #    and the exit if-block can follow here
                    if self.go_through_recursive(board, bb):  
                       return True
                # This index has no possible value, so backtrack!
                return False
```

Comment: could you provide the code for `check` method ?

Comment: It is not necessary. It was a function I used during debugging. Just removed it.